# java - How to find whether the url is utf-8 or utf-16

Tags: java, xml

How to find whether the URL is UTF-8 or UTF-16 in Java?

For example, [this URL](http://www.androidpeople.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/example.xml) is UTF-8.

Comment: The server response should include, in the `Content-Type` header field, a subfield called `charset`. That contains values such as UTF-8, UTF-16, etc.

Comment: @jleedev: If you read beyond the literal meaning of the OP's words, I think they actually mean the content retrieved by the URL, not the URL itself. :-)

Comment: In a single code i need to parse both utf-8 & utf -16 xml file ?....

Comment: Actually, the XML page returned by the URL you link to is pure ASCII.

Comment: @Android please spend some time reading your question (and correcting it), currently it doesn't make any sense. Do not confuse and URL with the document being returned by the URL. Also, the same URL can return different results based on the client used to call it. I can only assume that you wanted to ask about the encoding of the returned document because URLs are always ascii, regarding URLs please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Answer (score 3):

XML messages specify the encoding type.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. But, I need in a single code i need to parse both utf-8 & utf -16 xml file ? How to do it ?..

Comment: If you are using an XML parser, it will do the encoding for you.  If you are doing your own parser, you need to read this line and examine the encoding.  If you are able to write your own XML parser, this should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the other answers, there are two ways to specify the encoding of a document returned via HTTP:

- as part of the `Content-Type` header field
- encoding declaration inside the XML file (e.g. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)

However, both of these are optional. According to the HTTP spec, the encoding defaults to ISO 8859-1 is not specified. With an XML file, if the file is supplied with an HTTP Content-Typ header, this is the correct encoding. Otherwise, the default is UTF-8 or UTF-16 (depending on the presence of a [byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM).

So if you know the content is in UTF-8 or in UTF-16, check for the BOM. If it's there, it's UTF-16, otherwise UTF-8. See e.g. http://www.opentag.com/xfaq_enc.htm#enc_default for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're after the encoding of the representation of the resource addressed by this URL.

A resource at a given URI may have multiple representations. Thus, you can't really know generally in advance the content type and encoding of the representation you get until you actually get it. Using the HTTP `HEAD` method can give you some indication as to which content types and encodings the server is willing to offer. This will also vary depending on the headers your client sends (`Accept: ...`).
If you want to learn more about this, look for "Content-type negotiation".

Doing a `HEAD` or `GET` request should return a `Content-Type` header with the appropriate `charset` field. If no content-type negotiation takes place on this server (which is often the case), this will not vary.

If you're using `HttpURLConnection` in Java, you can see the headers using `getHeaderFieldKey` and `getHeaderField`.